# Oracle Client 11g R2

Tags: oracle, oracleclient, system.data.oracleclient

I have installed Oracle Client. 
Furthermore, the registry contains Oracle variables, and files are available in the installation folder. Also tns ping is functioning.

However the when I try to create data source, the driver is not available. Any suggestion?

Comment: (Edit: moved from Answer to Comment) Need a little more context here. Oracle client installed on YOUR_MACHINE allows application YOUR_APPLICATION to connect to an Oracle database while running on YOUR_MACHINE. When you say "the driver is not available", this tells me that when YOUR_APPLICATION tries to connect to Oracle database, it is giving you some kind of error message about the driver. Please let us know what YOUR_APPLICATION is (SQL Developer? Toad? Excel? Custom java application?), what you do to get the error, and the exact text of the error you get.

Comment: I want to create Oracle ODBC/OLE DB data source. For that I need Oracle Client. However when I open  "Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Datasources (ODBC)" (Win 7) and click on "Add new data source", the installed Oracle Client/Driver is not available. I need it for QlikView app.

Comment: Since tns ping functions and the computer recognizes sqlplus command, maybe the problem is in path? If yes, now can I check that out, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I Installed "Administrative" version - not it`s available.
Thx anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I Installed "Administrative" version - not it`s available.